# Elasticsearch 2.0.0 on Django-Haystack 2.4.1 Default Operator 'OR'

Tags: django, ubuntu, elasticsearch, django-haystack, elasticsearch-2.0

When I was developing locally, I tried both Elasticsearch 2.0.0 and 1.7.4. However, I used v1.7.4 because when I used v2.0.0, my search queries would not return results with similar words as you'd expect when setting `HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR'` (For example: *q=Footbal* should also return results with *Football*)

However, as I began to deploy my website in an Ubuntu Digital Ocean VPS, elasticsearch has deprecated 1.7.4 and provides [2.0.0 as the main download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch).

I installed elasticsearch in my VPS via APT repository [following this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html). I installed the elasticsearch binding via `pip install elasticsearch` in my virtualenv. And I installed django-haystack via `pip install git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack` because many have indicated that the one installed via `pip install django-haystack` was faulty. This was also installed in my virtualenv.

How do I enable the Haystack Default Operator to be "OR" to find similar queries?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Haystack Documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#elasticsearch): "Haystack currently only supports ElasticSearch 1.x. ElasticSearch 2.x is not supported yet." If you're using Ubuntu, you can find instructions on downloading Elasticsearch 1.7.x using `apt-get` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/setup-repositories.html).